# Javascript RegEx - Enforcing two max-lengths

Tags: javascript, regex, maxlength

It's been a while that I am juggling around this. Hope you can give me
some pointers.

All I want to achieve is, the string should contain **EXACTLY** 4 '-' and 10 digits in any giver order.

I created this regex : ^(-*\d-*){10}$ 
It does enforce max-length of 10 on digits but I am not getting a way to implement max-length of 4 for '-'

Thanks

Comment: As @stribizhev says, we need to know what should be considered valid and what should be considered invalid.  For instance, should `----1234567890` pass?  What about `12345----67890`?  Or `12-34-56-78-90`?

Comment: @stribizhev since when cannot the regex count? The `{n,m}` quantifier does precisely that.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: The quantifier `{n,m}` is just matching something a *specified* number of times, so it is not counting.

Comment: @stribizhev - what exactly do you do with the count?  You match a string based on a pattern if the count is within a specific range... therefore the quantifier allows you to match using a specific count.  If you wanted to return the count through a return group, that is a completely different matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's a pattern:

```
^(?=(?:\d*?-){4}\d*$)(?=(?:-*?\d){10}-*$).{14}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gO1cE5/1)

Explanation:

- The main part is `^.{14}$` which simply checks there are 14 characters in the string.
- Then, there are two lookaheads at the start:

  - `(?=(?:\d*?-){4}\d*$)`
  - `(?=(?:-*?\d){10}-*$)`

  The first one checks the hyphens, and the second one checks the digits and make sure the count is correct. Both match the entire input string and are very similar so let's just take a look at the first one.

  - `(?:\d*?-){4}` matches any number of digits (or none) followed by a hyphen, four times. After this match, we know there are four hyphens. (I used an ungreedy quantifier (`*?`) just to prevent useless backtracking, as an optimization)
  - `\d*$` just makes sure the rest of the string is only made of digits.

Comment: Thanks @Lucas !!  .. This is precisely what I was looking for .

Comment: But @Lucas I just have a question .. In "(?:\d*?-){4}" portion, why have you used "?" after "\d*". As pattern works fine without these too.

Comment: @Lakha that's just an optimization, it prevents useless backtracking. I should have stated that in the answer.